# How do you style a text input so that there's an icon on the left without using background-image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a text input similar to the username and password input shown in Pearson's TestNav login (ignore the yellow box).

[image: Pearson's TestNav Login]

To make the icon on the left, they use the background-image property. I was wondering if it was possible to achieve the same effect without using any images. [I've gotten pretty close](https://jsfiddle.net/f1fugx5r/3/), but there are two problems. The border to the right of the icon box is rounded, and if you click the icon it doesn't focus the input. I tried making the input box background transparent and putting the icon behind it, but Chrome overrides the background color if the site is in the password manager.

Here's the CSS/HTML of my attempt:
HTML:

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.field input {
    outline: none;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 44px;
    position: absolute;

    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(186,213,232,1);

    transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.field input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #2977FF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(186,213,232,1);
}

.field .icon {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your icon div to a label

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" id="this-input">
  <label class="icon" for="this-input">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

That way when it is clicked it focuses the element it references (for="this-input")

To fix the border radius. Change the icon style from

```
border-radius: 3px;
```

to

```
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
```

This starts from top left corner and says 3px for the top left, then 0 for top right, 0 for bottom right, and 3px for bottom left borners

Answer (score 0):

you can use use: input:before and style that with an icon font like fontawesome as content.

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="this-input" class="icon-whatever" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The round shape can be removed by making use of border-radius as in your case,
    
border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

You need Javascript to focus the input tag. Because the .icon class is no part of the input tag(input tag is seperate and .icon is seperate in your code). In order to do that use focus() function

I hope this helps

```js
function cool()
{
  document.getElementById("cool").focus();
}
```

```css
.field input {
    outline: none;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 44px;
    position: absolute;

    width: 260px;
    height: 40px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(186,213,232,1);

    transition: border 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.field input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #2977FF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgba(186,213,232,1);
}

.field .icon {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius:0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" id=cool>
  <div class="icon" onclick="cool()">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```